# Suppressing generation of bytecode by sphinx-build

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-sphinx, bytecode

How do I suppress the generation of bytecode (`.pyc`) when running `sphinx-build`?

I've tried

```
sys.dont_write_bytecode = True
```

in my `conf.py`, but that has no effect. And I see no way to set an environment variable (`PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE`) or compiler flag (`-B`) using `sphinx-build` options.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. `sys.dont_write_bytecode = True` works for me.

Comment: @mzjn: In `conf.py`? Where do you put it (in what order)?

Comment: Yes, in conf.py. At the beginning (after `import sys`) or at the end of the file. No difference.

Comment: @mzjn: Hmm. I can't reproduce your inability to reproduce. I'm using `sphinx-build -b html -a -E ./doc/source ./doc/build` and thought one of those flags might be the cause, but it isn't. Is there anywhere else that could be overriding `sys.dont_write_bytecode`?